# Share sessions between HTTP and WebSocket server? (alt. find session by id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, websocket, session-cookies

In my initializers I start a rails server in a new thread. Cookie are apparently not sent in a normal socket message (which I get). In order to perform auth on a message basis, I would like to bind sessions to the sockets internally. Transporting the session_id explicitly would not be a problem for me but I have not yet found a way to retrieve a session via it's ID. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here I go:

```
def decrypt_session_cookie(cookie)
  cookie = CGI.unescape(cookie)
  config = Rails.application.config

  encrypted_cookie_salt = config.action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt               #     "encrypted cookie" by default
  encrypted_signed_cookie_salt = config.action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt # "signed encrypted cookie" by default

  key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(config.secret_key_base, iterations: 1000)
  secret = key_generator.generate_key(encrypted_cookie_salt)
  sign_secret = key_generator.generate_key(encrypted_signed_cookie_salt)

  encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, sign_secret)
  encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(cookie)
end
```

Source: http://big-elephants.com/2014-01/handling-rails-4-sessions-with-go/

This way I was able to decrypt the cookie which I just sent in the initial message.